# How do I make outdoor GFCI into 2 separate circuits?

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 20 amp double pole breaker with 12/2 wire being used. 1 pole is for the GFCI outlets that cover the front/back yard. The 2nd pole is used for indoor bathrooms.

I want to separate my backyard outlets from my front yard outlets because I have pumps for multiple fish ponds, heaters, etc. being run. When the holidays comes around and decorations go up in the front, issues start to arise with tripping breakers.

What I would like to do is just leave the back outlets as they are, but remove the daisy chain to the front yard and put it on a new circuit of its own. Replace the receptacle with a 20amp rated, run with 12/2 on its own 20 amp single pole breaker. ( overkill I know but may as well )

This is an existing property, and I’m trying to find the easiest way to get this accomplished.

I guess my next big thing to figure out would be how I would run from the panel box to the front yard to get my separate circuit dream.

Comment: Hard to give much insight when you don't specify how they are connected - in most houses, if the front and back yard outlets are tied together, that junction is somewhere in the house, and you'd just run new wire from that point, with no need to run wire all the way outside. It's not clear how yours are connected if that's not an obvious choice for you. Second observation is that it would appear to make more sense to take the bathrooms off this breaker (and put them on a new one) and put both front and back yard on the double breaker, one on each pole. Pictures could be [edit]ed in.

Comment: I was considering switching the bathrooms onto its own breaker, but I was still left with the head scratcher of separating the front from the back to have them on the double pole.                                           I will post pictures tomorrow morning and also check out where the junction in the house could possibly be. 
I appreciate your answer very much.

Comment: Junction should be at a outlet, instead of a separate junction box(might need to be added).  circuit should go from panel to first outlet to next outlet then to front outlets(or reverse).  Direction of circuit should be from panel to closest outlet, then go further.  People are cheap and lazy and don't like to double back circuits.

Comment: I would suggest mapping out the layout of the wiring so you know exactly which outlets are on each pole of the twin 20A and in exactly what order they're connected. Once you've got that, it should become reasonably obvious where and how to make the split.

Comment: While you're at it (the 4 most dangerous words in remodeling), you  might consider adding one or two backyard "utility" outlets on the front-yard outlet circuit. That way you can plug in Christmas lights, weed whackers or other things in the back without impacting all the more "permanent" backyard things - pumps, heaters, etc.

Comment: @crip659 there is no should in wiring locations and directions. Most are wired from the panel to the closest outlet but this is to save wire, a couple weeks back I was helping my kids troubleshoot a failed backstabbed circuit and the first receptacle was the furthest away, crazy and unusual. Totally code legal and not a DIY.